# Python Crypto AES ImportError on Fedora

Tags: python, pycrypto, fedora-23

I have installed pycrypto:

```
$> sudo pip install pycrypto

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycrypto in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
```

And I import like this in my python file

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES:
```

But I still get this when running my python file

```
ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher
```

This is on a Fedora23 machine.

I recently installed and run the same code on a centos7 and on that machine I had to do:

```
yum install python-devel
pip install pycrypto
```

But that does not help on the Fedora machine.
I searched and found a few answers saying to install pycrypto and to import using capital C. But it seems this is some other problem...

Comment: Ok, so I think I found out the problem. And it was all about the virtual environment. When installing pycrypto inside the virtual environment, I should not have used "sudo" to install.